# InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Key format must be RAW with REST template and Spring4

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, resttemplate

I am using REST template to invoke https rest APIs.

I am getting the below error, if i add a custom provider in java.security file. Otherwise the rest client code is working fine using rest template. I am adding the custom provider at number 3, the requested position by the custom provider.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://10.170.4.86:8070/callback":java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Key format must be RAW; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Key format must be RAW
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:357)
        at com.wsclient.RestClient.invokeCallbackURL(RestClient.java:83)
        at com.service.processor.CryptoProcessor.processDelayMessage(CryptoProcessor.java:238)
        at com.messaging.mdp.MessageReceiver.onDelay(MessageReceiver.java:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:327)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:253)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:756)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:167)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1241)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:660)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:989)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:82)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Key format must be RAW
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:290)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
```

The order of java.security:-

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.5=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.6=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.7=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.8=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.9=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.10=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.3=customProviderImpl
```

The Rest client code below:-

```
ublic class RestClientConfig {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
      .getLogger(RestClientConfig.class);

  @Bean
  public RestOperations restOperations(
      ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory)
      throws Exception {
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
  }


  @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory(
            @Value("${read.timeout.connector}") String readTimeout,
            HttpClient httpClient) {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComClientFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                httpClient);
        httpComClientFactory.setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(readTimeout));
        httpComClientFactory.setReadTimeout(Integer.parseInt(readTimeout));
        return httpComClientFactory;
    }


  @Bean
  public HttpClient getHttpClient(
      @Value("${keystore.file}") String keyfile,
      @Value("${keystore.pass}") String keypass,
      @Value("${keystore.type}") String keystoreType,
      @Value("${truststore.file}") String trustfile,
      @Value("${truststore.pass}") String trustpass,
      @Value("${truststore.type}") String trusttype)
      throws Exception {
      Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType);
    FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File(keyfile));
    try {
      keyStore.load(instream, keypass.toCharArray());
    }
    finally {
      instream.close();
    }

    LOG.debug("trustfile  " + trustfile);

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trusttype);
    instream = new FileInputStream(new File(trustfile));
    try {
      trustStore.load(instream, trustpass.toCharArray());
    }
    finally {
      instream.close();
    }

    /*TrustStrategy trustStrategy           = new 
            TrustSelfSignedStrategy();*/
    TrustStrategy ts = new TrustStrategy() {
      @Override
      public boolean isTrusted(
          X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
          throws CertificateException {
        return true; // TODO : revisit
      }
    };
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
//    SSLContext sslcontext1=SSLContext.getInstance("", "");
//    sslcontext1.in
    SSLContext sslcontext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keypass.toCharArray())
        .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, ts)
        .build();

    final HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {

      @Override
      public boolean verify(
          String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(

        sslcontext, new String[] {
            "TLSv1.2" }, null,

        SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    /*SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null,
            hv);*/

    return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

  }

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
```

Comment: You haven't needed the `Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());` line since Java 1.3. Remove it. What are the values of the various KeyStore parameters?

Comment: Keystore type is JKS for both truststore and keystore.

Comment: By putting the 'custom' provider (which I see you anonymized here) high in the list it got selected over a builtin provider for some operation JSSE (i.e. TLS) needs, but it doesn't support the needed (standard) functionality. If you identify the exact version of Java, the linenumbers of the two `startHandshake` frames could be looked up and will probably identify the affected operation. Alternatively if you run with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` and capture the output that may identify it or at least narrow the range of possibilities. ...

Comment: ... If 'custom' is used only in your own code, you would do better to ignore their 'requested position' and put it (near) last in the provider list and specify it explicitly in `getInstance` calls. If it's used in code that can't specify it, but only at times that don't overlap with TLS connections, you might manage by dynamically reordering the provider list -- e.g., initially put custom at end, make TLS connection, move custom to #3, call code that needs it at #3, etc. But depending on your app that could be complicated and fragile.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when the installation of an SDK requested that their security provider to be listed in the third position in java.security. During connection requests the app started to display these exceptions:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Key format must be RAW
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:260)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1529)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1502)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Key format must be RAW
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateMasterSecret(Handshaker.java:1175)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateKeys(Handshaker.java:1110)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1078)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Key format must be RAW
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsMasterSecretGenerator.engineInit(TlsMasterSecretGenerator.java:67)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:454)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.init(KeyGenerator.java:430)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateMasterSecret(Handshaker.java:1163)
    ... 35 more
```

Once I moved that provider at the bottom of the list of providers in java.security, connection worked perfectly fine.
At least move the CustomProvider after the SSLProvider because during the connection handshake a function is called from the CustomProvider instead of SSLProvider